# Why do you take the natural logarithm plus one?

Tags: regression, nonlinear

I have read in many different studies now that take the natural logarithm of one plus x.
For example, in econometrics many studies use the natural logarithm of one plus the total assets.

I do not understand why, because assets are so big anyways that adding one would not make a difference, or?

For example:

Natural Logarithm of one plus Assets(1,000,000) would be NL(1,000,001).

Comment: This is just a guess. If one of the numbers in the data set is equal to $0$ then $\log(0)$ becomes undefined, or if you prefer, $-\infty$. To keep your quantities as real numbers you add $+1$ to them. In addition, $\log(1+x) \approx  x$ if $x$ is a small quantity (the linear approximation).

Comment: Thank you so much, so it is a rather "technical" cue and I can simply add one by log(1+x) without worrying that I skew the data?

Comment: You are definitely changing the distribution of your data, however, since you know what function was applied to your data, you can always go back to the original by reversing the process, so changing the data distribution is not a problem. In fact, it might actually be a good thing, since after taking logs your data will range from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, so in particular, there might be a chance that the transformed data will be normally distributed (which is probably what you want).

Comment: Whenever this transformation makes sense -- because values are $\ge 0$ -- the usual effect will be to reduce skewness in the data.

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki Negative results are impossible with this translation. The point is to map values 0 upwards to 0 upwards.

Comment: This transformation is arbitrary and can really move estimates around depending on what you add to zero. More on this, with alternatives, [here](https://www.nber.org/papers/w30735).

Comment: @dimitriy You're referring to $\log (x + c), c > 0, x \ge 0$, but nothing in the question is about that.

Comment: @NickCox Isn’t the question about $\ln (x + c)$ for $c=1$? I am making a claim that adding a penny or a dollar can have a noticeable impact on the coefficients and the choice seems arbitrary.

Comment: That is so and what Mullahy and Norton are on about in the paper you cite. I think the proof of the pudding is in the eating and to be sure in practice, one needs to think about units.